# how to move up previous values in sequences?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nested, time-series, sequence

I have a df like the following ...

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[8001,7999,np.nan,8030,9900, 9342,9324,8534,8358,9457,  np.nan ,8999,8492,np.nan,np.nan],
                   "B":[201,209,298,300,np.nan, 342,324,854,858,457, 145,189,192,134,135],
                  "C":[11991,15631,47998,38030,19900, 29342,np.nan,28534,28358,29457, 27245,28999,28492,29334,28234]}, index=pd.Index('2019-06-17 00:00:00','2019-06-17 00:01:01', '2019-06-17 00:02:00', '2019-06-17 00:03:04', '2020-06-17 00:04:00', '2020-06-17 00:05:00', '2020-06-17 00:06:00', '2020-06-17 00:07:00','2020-06-17 00:08:00','2020-06-17 00:09:00','2020-06-17 00:10:00','2020-06-17 00:11:00','2020-06-17 00:12:00','2020-06-17 00:13:00', '2020-06-17 00:14:00'))

                 Time     A     B       C
'2019-06-17 00:00:00'  8001   201   11991
'2019-06-17 00:01:01'  7999   209   15631
'2019-06-17 00:02:00'  7998   298   47998
'2019-06-17 00:03:04'  NaN    300   38030
'2020-06-17 00:04:00'  9900   NaN   19900
'2020-06-17 00:05:00'  9342   342   29342
'2020-06-17 00:06:00'  9324   324     NaN
'2020-06-17 00:07:00'  8534   854   28534
'2020-06-17 00:08:00'  8358   858   28358
'2020-06-17 00:09:00'  9457   457   29457
'2020-06-17 00:10:00'   NaN   145   27245
'2020-06-17 00:11:00'  8999   189   28999
'2020-06-17 00:12:00'  8492   192   28492
'2020-06-17 00:13:00'   NaN   134   29334
'2020-06-17 00:14:00'   NaN   135   28234
```

... and I can sequentialize it. So far no problem.
(I already got code for this, so the outcome for a sequence_Length==5 is:)

```
array([    
   [['2019-06-17 00:00:00'  8001    201   11991 ]
    ['2019-06-17 00:01:01'  7999    209   15631 ]
    ['2019-06-17 00:02:00'  7998    298   47998 ]
    ['2019-06-17 00:03:04'   NaN    300   38030 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:04:00'  9900    NaN   19900 ]]
 
   [['2019-06-17 00:01:01'  7999    209   15631 ]
    ['2019-06-17 00:02:00'  7998    298   47998 ]
    ['2019-06-17 00:03:04'   NaN    300   38030 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:04:00'  9900    NaN   19900 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:05:00'  9342    342   29342 ]]

   [['2019-06-17 00:02:00'  7998    298   47998 ]
    ['2019-06-17 00:03:04'   NaN    300   38030 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:04:00'  9900    NaN   19900 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:05:00'  9342    342   29342 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:06:00'  9324    324     NaN ]]

   [['2019-06-17 00:03:04'   NaN    300   38030 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:04:00'  9900    NaN   19900 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:05:00'  9342    342   29342 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:06:00'  9324    324     NaN ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:07:00'  8534    854   28534 ]]

   [['2020-06-17 00:04:00'  9900    NaN   19900 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:05:00'  9342    342   29342 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:06:00'  9324    324     NaN ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:07:00'  8534    854   28534 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:08:00'  8358    858   28358 ]]

   [['2020-06-17 00:05:00'  9342    342   29342 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:06:00'  9324    324     NaN ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:07:00'  8534    854   28534 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:08:00'  8358    858   28358 ] 
    ['2020-06-17 00:09:00'  9457    457   29457 ]]

   [['2020-06-17 00:06:00'  9324    324     NaN ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:07:00'  8534    854   28534 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:08:00'  8358    858   28358 ] 
    ['2020-06-17 00:09:00'  9457    457   29457 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:10:00'   NaN    145   27245 ]]

   [['2020-06-17 00:07:00'  8534    854   28534 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:08:00'  8358    858   28358 ] 
    ['2020-06-17 00:09:00'  9457    457   29457 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:10:00'   NaN    145   27245 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:11:00'  8999    189   28999 ]]

   [['2020-06-17 00:08:00'  8358    858   28358 ] 
    ['2020-06-17 00:09:00'  9457    457   29457 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:10:00'   NaN    145   27245 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:11:00'  8999    189   28999 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:12:00'  8492    192   28492 ]]

   [['2020-06-17 00:09:00'  9457    457   29457 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:10:00'   NaN    145   27245 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:11:00'  8999    189   28999 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:12:00'  8492    192   28492 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:13:00'   NaN    134   29334 ]]

   [['2020-06-17 00:10:00'   NaN    145   27245 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:11:00'  8999    189   28999 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:12:00'  8492    192   28492 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:13:00'   NaN    134   29334 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:14:00'   NaN    135   28234 ]]
                                                     ])
# (i kept the timeindices in there, to clear things up)
```

I cant work with nans, but i also am not allowed to interpolate the data. So:

**Question:**
How do I move up all the previous values to where the nans are?
(like in this example:)

```
# Before:
   [['2020-06-17 00:10:00'   NaN    145   27245 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:11:00'  8999    189   28999 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:12:00'  8492    192   28492 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:13:00'   NaN    134   29334 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:14:00'   NaN    135   28234 ]]

# Expected Result:          # v-- the last 5 valid values in "A" till the current index (=='2020-06-17 00:14:00')
   [['2020-06-17 00:10:00'  8534    145   27245 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:11:00'  8358    189   28999 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:12:00'  9457    192   28492 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:13:00'  8999    134   29334 ]
    ['2020-06-17 00:14:00'  8492    135   28234 ]]
```

probably a few early samples get lost, when the sequence length gets too high, but thats okay. (since there could be a very high amount of nans in one column)

**EDIT:** (how to do this?)
In steps it would be like this:

Step 1: (In the df) get the X last valid elements up to date (eg. 00:14:00') (as list)
Step 2: Replace the "column" (in the nested list) by the list from Step 1 (how to select it)